# Decimal property value doesn't pass to webservice method in c#

Tags: .net, web-services, c#-4.0

I have an `Invoice` class. It has a property as `Line` class type. Line has some decimal properties. Here is a  part of my code:

```
    Invoice invoice = new Invoice()
            {
                aliciAlias = "defaultpk",
                aliciBinaNo = "B2", 
                 ...
                 malzemeler = new Line[1]
                        {
                            new Line()
                                {
                                   MalzemeTutari = 100,...
                                 }...
                        }
```

I give the invoice to a webservice method as parameter, I see MalzemeTutari's value is 0. Do you have any suggestion about it? Where is my mistake?

Comment: You should propose more information

Comment: @user1767754 what should I more post about my code? If you will tell me I will eidt my question.

Comment: Please post the declaration of both Line and Invoice, as we have a hard time going over your code telepathically.